# Took SurveyGopher survey on SO but forgot to get Careers invite

Tags: support, jobs, stack-overflow-developer-survey

I took the SurveyGopher survey on SO, which offered an invite to Careers, but I forgot at the end to get it. Obviously I can't take the survey over again. Is there any way to contact an admin so that I can get the Careers invite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request an invite at any time at http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one.  We review that list every few days, and if you're active on SO or any OSS project that's generally enough to warrant an invite.

In your case, I already went ahead and looked at your SO activity and sent you an invite.